# Entity Framework and Related Table Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables. Person and Cities. Person table has CitiID. Cities has CityID and CityName. I just want to get City Name from table Cities. There is a foreign key between them. I can't find necessary code. (Probably so easy question but i really can't figure out right now and hard to find answer because it's keywords are so general)

```
public ActionResult Index (int id)
{
    var personInfo = db.Person.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonID == id);

    var person = new PersonVM(); // This is my model view.

    person.Name = personInfo.Name; // OK
    person.Surname = personInfo.Surname; // OK
    person.CityName = ??? // personInfo.Cities.???

    return View(person);
}
```

Comment: What does your `Person` and `Cities` classes look like?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I found two solution. I couldn't find them before because they are so easy than i guess:

```
var person = new PersonVM(){CityName = personInfo.Cities.CityName};
```

or

```
person.CityName = personInfo.Cities.CityName
```

Comment: Better yet: var person = new PersonVM {  Name = personInfo.Name,  Surname = personInfo.Surname, CityName = personInfo.Cities.CityName } Even better is AuotMapper which will do them all in 1 step with a little config.